# How to solve the issue of mixing version of support libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-multidex, android-appcompat

I received an update to android SDK. After the update, when I open a project, Android Studio recommends to update Android Gradle to v 2.3.0 and Gradle to v 3.3. I updated the project as recommended. After that I found an ugly red line under the appcompat-v7:25.2.0' (see pic).

[image]

[image]

The error, according to android studio, is that I am mixing versions of support libraries (v 25 and 24), but I didn’t find any support library of v24. I tried to build a signed apk, but app build failed (using V2 / full apk signature), so I searched the web and I found one solution to this problem by adding this line to the build.gradle: multiDexEnabled  true. Adding that line fixed the problem of generating signed apk, although the red line of error was still there, it didn’t get rid of it.

[image]

Then I installed the signed apk on two phones, one running Android 6.0 and the other one is running Android 4.4.2. The app runs smoothly on Android 6.0 and crashes on start on Android 4.4.2 (I set minSdkVersion to 19).

[image]

My questions are: how can fix that error in the gradle permanently? Is adding the line “multiDexEnabled” to gradle really needed? How can I run my app on android 4.4.2 without crashing?

Comment: no one has an answer?!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm had the same issue, just add these lines:

```
  compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}"
  compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
```

In your case supportLibVersion is 25.2.0.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.